# 2007 iMac Blurred Screen of Death

Tags: mac, macos, imac, startup

I'm running OS X 10.10.1 on a 2007 iMac (Intel based) I have tried to boot into the recovery HD, but it just continues with the boot as if I have never pressed cmd-r. When it does finally boot; it goes to a screen with the spinning beach-ball of death and a blurred background. I have reinstalled the RAM twice, and have reset the NVRAM and PRAM.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Cmd/R should boot to recovery, but if it finds no recovery I don't think that machine can do Internet Recovery, so it could be down to boot from DVD or a bootable USB - https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT4718

Comment: Sounds like I have to go to the apple store soon then. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hard Drive Failed... Went to apple and they told me :(

Answer (score -1):

Yosemite is taking all RAM during the dead start, allow it to boot for more than 40 minutes.  The screen will eventually go black, allow it to continue... finally, it will finish the start up and present the normal login screen.   After 10 minutes of sluggish operation, it will be normal.
Eventually Apple may fix the problem.